# How to add double quotes to both keys and values for an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, buffer, stringify

I have a an array containing buffer data as below

```
 [{ Buffer_Data: <Buffer b5 eb 2d> },{ Buffer_Data: <Buffer b5 eb 2d> },{ Buffer_Data: <Buffer b5 eb 2d> },{ Buffer_Data: <Buffer b5 eb 2d> }]
```

I want double quotes to be added to both key and values and the result should be as below.

```
 [{ "Buffer_Data": "<Buffer b5 eb 2d>" },{ "Buffer_Data": "<Buffer b5 eb 2d>" },{ "Buffer_Data": "<Buffer b5 eb 2d>" },{ "Buffer_Data": "<Buffer b5 eb 2d>" }]
```

I have tried JSON.stringify but it is giving me the buffer data in invalid format. How can I convert this to array with double quotes. Please help

Here is my code

```
 stream = fs.createReadStream('files/uploaded_files/' + req.body.fileName);
          var bufferdata = [];
        stream.on('data', async function (chunk) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.Buffer_Data =  Buffer.from(chunk.toString('binary'), 'base64');
            bufferdata.push(obj)
        });
        stream.on('end', async function(){
        var new_buffer_data = JSON.stringify(bufferdata) // This is giving invalid value
      })
```

Code I tried

```
    stream = fs.createReadStream('files/uploaded_files/' + req.body.fileName);
          var bufferdata = [];
        stream.on('data', async function (chunk) {
            var bytes = chunk.map(str => parseInt(str, 16));
              const buf = Buffer.from(bytes);
              var obj = {};
              obj.Buffer_Data = buf;
            buffer.push(obj)
        });
        stream.on('end', async function(){
         const stringified = JSON.stringify(buffer.map(obj => ({Buffer_Data: stringifyBuffer(obj.Buffer_Data)})));
      
        console.log(stringified);
      })
```

Comment: *"I have a an array containing buffer data as below"* ... Can you show your code that you have it like that? Maybe all you have is a string formatted as such.

Comment: @GetSet stream = fs.createReadStream('files/uploaded_files/' + req.body.fileName);

          var bufferdata = [];

        stream.on('data', async function (chunk) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.Buffer_Data =  Buffer.from(chunk.toString('binary'), 'base64');
            bufferdata.push(obj)
        });
        stream.on('end', async function(){
  var new_buffer_data = JSON.stringify(bufferdata) // This is giving invalid value
      })

Comment: This is my code

Comment: Put your code in your question, not here in comments.

Comment: @GetSet Yes, I added it in the question

Comment: @GetSet Yes, I am getting an error while stringifying the array. Even regex is fine, I just need to add double quotes. Later I need to pass it to DB

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify the array of objects with [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) data in the format that you specified using this method:

`./so-71389714.mjs`:

```js
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';

function stringifyBuffer (buf) {
  let result = '<Buffer';

  for (const byte of buf) {
    result += ` ${byte.toString(16)}`;
  }

  result += '>';
  return result;
}

const bytes = ['b5', 'eb', '2d'].map(str => parseInt(str, 16));
const buf = Buffer.from(bytes);
const obj = {Buffer_Data: buf};

// This is the array in your question
const array = [obj, obj, obj, obj];

const stringified = JSON.stringify(array.map(obj => ({Buffer_Data: stringifyBuffer(obj.Buffer_Data)})));

console.log(stringified);
```

```
$ node so-71389714.mjs
[{"Buffer_Data":"<Buffer b5 eb 2d>"},{"Buffer_Data":"<Buffer b5 eb 2d>"},{"Buffer_Data":"<Buffer b5 eb 2d>"},{"Buffer_Data":"<Buffer b5 eb 2d>"}]
```

Comment: How would this work in my case. Mine is already converted to buffer

Comment: @Saisri The `stringified` value in my answer is of the exact type that you requested in your question: it is a string of JSON data, created from an array of objects whose keys and values are of type `string`, and because the JSON spec specifies that such components must be double quoted, they are double quoted after being stringified.

Comment: I have tried this in my code in stream.on('end') function, but it is not giving me the required output  const stringified = JSON.stringify(bufferdata.map(obj => ({Buffer_Data: stringifyBuffer(obj.Buffer_Data)})));

console.log(stringified);

Comment: because my object obj.Buffer_Data already contains <buffer

Comment: I have tried you code and added whatever I tried in the question above It is working, but it is not giving a base64 as output. it is giving me like [{"Buffer_Data":"<Buffer 16 1 15 16>"}]

Comment: @Saisri Correct: that is exactly the desired schema that you specified for output.

Comment: No it should be in base64 format [{"Buffer_Data":"<Buffer b5 eb 2d>"}]

Comment: @Saisri It sound like you're either unsure about the shema that you need or are unsure about how to communicate it. Unless you clearly communicate exactly what it is that you need, I'm sorry, but I can't help you.